# Need to display multiple columns of information for a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a history entry in my table which provides information about the ticket like the escalation level, assigned to level, status. All this information is in a history field for a particular Ticket. I need to display multiple columns of history information for a partiuclar ticket. Like display tickets which contain history information like "Esclataed to Level 2" in a single column, then "status changed from closed to resolved" in a different column and so on. Basically depending on the conditions I provide, I want to display a different column.

Below is my code:

```
Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,Path,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,PARENT_ID,Lvl,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(PROBLEM_TYPE_ID as varchar(500))
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,PARENT_ID
           ,Lvl=1
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   problem_type 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(PARENT_ID,-1) else PROBLEM_TYPE_ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME)) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(concat(cteHB.Path,'.',cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,cteCD.PARENT_ID,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   problem_type cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.PARENT_ID = cteHB.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID )
    ,cteFinalHier as (
        Select B.R1  
              ,C.R2
              ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
              ,A.PARENT_ID
              ,A.Lvl
              ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
              ,A.Seq                                      -- < Included for Illustration
              ,A.Path                                     -- < Included for Illustration
         From cteHB A
         Join cteR1 B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
         Join cteR2 C on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
    )
Select A.Job_ticket_id
      ,[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] =B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
      ,custom1.string_value
      ,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_DATE
      ,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT
    ,A.Report_Date
      ,A.LAST_UPDATED
      ,a.STATUS_TYPE_ID AS 'Ticket_Status'
      ,A.Close_Date
      ,A.TECH_GROUP_ID
       ,A.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID
      ,TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.LEVEL_NUMBER
      ,PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
      ,TECH_GROUP.NAME
      ,DATEDIFF(MINute, A.REPORT_DATE,A.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) as 'time_to_accept'                   
      , DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],A.[CLOSE_DATE]) as 'time_to_resolve'

      -----------------------only for tickets open older than 72 hours------------------------------
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,a.LAST_UPDATED,getdate()) as 'Time_after_Update'
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,case WHEN DATEDIFF(MINute, A.REPORT_DATE,A.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) <= 10                        -- < for tickets accepted withiin 10 miniutes and resolved within their priority level minutes
                and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],A.[CLOSE_DATE]) <= case PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
                                   WHEN 'low' then 960
                                   WHEN 'medium' then 480
                                   WHEN 'high' then 120
                                   WHEN 'Urgent' then 60
                                   end
  then 1
  else 0
  end
  AS [SLA Compliant]
  ,CAST ((sum(case WHEN DATEDIFF(MINute, A.REPORT_DATE,A.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) <= 10                     -- < for tickets accepted withiin 10 miniutes and resolved within their priority level minutes
                and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],A.[CLOSE_DATE]) <= case PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
                                   WHEN 'low' then 960
                                   WHEN 'medium' then 480
                                   WHEN 'high' then 120
                                   WHEN 'Urgent' then 60
                                   end
  then 1
  else 0
  end)*100.0)/COUNT(*) as money) as Percent_Compliant
  ------------------------------JOINS--------------------------------------------------                                                                                 
 From  JOB_TICKET A
 Join  cteFinalHier B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID

 INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[PRIORITY_TYPE] ON A.[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID] = [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID]

 INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[STATUS_TYPE] ON A.[STATUS_TYPE_ID] = [STATUS_TYPE].[STATUS_TYPE_ID]

  inner join [SWHD01].[dbo].TECH_GROUP_LEVEL on A.TECH_GROUP_LEVEL_ID=TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.ID

 join TECH_GROUP on TECH_GROUP.ID= TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.tech_group_id

 join ticket_custom_field custom1 on custom1.entity_id = a.job_ticket_id
join custom_field_definition custom_definition1 on custom_definition1.id=custom1.definition_id and custom_definition1.label='severity'

join HISTORY_ENTRY on a.JOB_TICKET_ID=HISTORY_ENTRY.JOB_TICKET_ID



 Cross Apply (Select Top 1 * from cteFinalHier Where B.R1 between R1 and R2 and Lvl=1) C

 -------------Tickets for the Last 6 months---------------------------------------------------

 where datediff(MONTH, A.REPORT_DATE, getdate()) <= 6
and TECH_GROUP.NAME like '%NOC%'
 and LEVEL_NUMBER ='2'
 and HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT  like '%Assigned to %Level 2%%'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Group By C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,a.JOB_TICKET_ID,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID, a.REPORT_DATE,a.CLOSE_DATE,SWHD01.dbo.PRIORITY_TYPE.PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME,a.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE,B.R1,a.LAST_UPDATED,a.STATUS_TYPE_ID,a.TECH_GROUP_ID,TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.LEVEL_NUMBER,TECH_GROUP.NAME,a.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID,custom1.STRING_VALUE,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_DATE,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT
 Order By B.R1
```

the current output is:
[image]

expected output is:
[image]

Comment: This is not hard -- you clearly can write a select statement -- what is the problem with having another column?

Comment: I actually have no idea about how to display different information from the same column in the output. that is the reason I have posted this for help. @Hogan

Answer (score 0):

*update based on comments*

This is exactly what my example is showing you how to do:

```
SELECT
  -- prior part of sql query here
  CASE WHEN ENTERY_TEXT like 'Assigned to%' THEN ENTRY_TEXT ELSE '' END AS ENTRY_TEXT,
  CASE WHEN ENTRY_TEXT like 'Escalated to%' OR
            ENTRY_TEXT like 'Deescalated to%' THEN ENTRY_TEXT ELSE '' END AS ENTRY_TEXT_2,
  -- rest of sql query here
```

Do you see how this is the same answer as my original, if you don't give any clear details then the answer has to be general.

---

*original answer*

So... you want to know how to do this?

```
SELECT
   --- ....
   CASE WHEN A=B THEN 'Esclataed to Level 2' ELSE '' END AS COL1_NAME,
   CASE WHEN C=D THEN 'status changed from closed to resolved' ELSE '' END AS COL2_NAME
   --- ...
```

Comment: what would A=B and C=D represnt in this case? @hogan

Comment: You said "Basically depending on the conditions I provide, I want to display a different column".  I've no idea what those conditions are -- you did not provide them.  So I used 4 variables to represent stuff with the condition being they are equal..

Comment: the conditions are basically "Esclataed to Level 2" and "status changed from closed to resolved" which should be extracted from the History column. So i will be displaying one column into 2 columns with tickets containing this data  "Esclataed to Level 2" and "status changed from closed to resolved" @hogan

Comment: @Sanky that makes no sense to me.  input data, expected output, concise business rules -- This is the only way I can be more helpful than I have been.  100 line queries, unreadable pictures, super confusing comments get nowhere late on a Friday.

Comment: Okay. I will try explaining again. I have got a table history_entry which contains entry_text as a column, This column entry_text contains information like status changed, esclated to, assidgned to and so on. But I just want to display some information from the entry_text column like "Esclataed to level 2" and "Status changed from closed to resolved" instead of displaying all the information from the entry_text column. If you can see the Expected output, I have two columns entry_text and Entry_text2 which needs to display this information. @hogan